# Full screen Terminal spread across both monitors on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu

I have a dual monitor setup, and I would like to get the **Terminal** to span both screens and for it to also be in fullscreen mode.

I would also like the **Terminal** to always open this way.

Comment: And what do you need that for? I am just asking to verify if, this could possibly be an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: I feel like asking whether something is an XY problem unnecessarily may be an XY problem.

Comment: I want emacs spread across both screens. There are a million other legitimate uses.